# How to move a set of files and directories, excluding another (sub-)set

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, find, mv

I have two bash arrays, one of them (named `toMove`) contains paths to files and directories **to move (not copy)** somewhere else, and the other one (named `exclude`) contains paths to files and directories to exclude from moving.

```
toMove=(
    tree/subtree1
    tree/subtree2
    tree/subtree3/leaffile3
)
exclude=(
    tree/subtree1/leafdir1
    tree/subtree2/leaffile2
)

# move code ?
```

This is the test directory structure:

```
mkdir -p tree/{subtree1/leafdir1,subtree2/leafdir2,subtree3/leafdir3}
touch tree/{subtree1/leaffile1,subtree2/leaffile2,subtree3/leaffile3}
tree tree
    tree
    ├── subtree1
    │   ├── leafdir1
    │   └── leaffile1
    ├── subtree2
    │   ├── leafdir2
    │   └── leaffile2
    └── subtree3
        ├── leafdir3
        └── leaffile3
```

Desired outcome after moving:

```
tree tree
    tree
    ├── subtree1
    │   └── leafdir1
    ├── subtree2
    │   └── leaffile2
    └── subtree3
        └── leafdir3

tree destination
    destination
    ├── subtree1
    │   └── leaffile1
    ├── subtree2
    │   └── leafdir2
    └── subtree3
        └── leaffile3
```

In `rsync`, there is an `--exclude-from=` option, that (in combination with the `--remove-source-files` option) does exactly what I want, but unfortunately `rsync` **copies files but I need to *move* them** (for performance reasons), if they are on the same filesystem.

The solution I have in mind, is using find to obtain a list of all paths (including the contents of the dirs) in the toMove array,  iterating over this list and filtering out all paths starting with the paths in the exclude array. Is this the right approach to the problem, or is there a simpler and/or more elegant way (possibly using some standard utilities) to solve this?

UPDATE:

As it turns out, this problem is not as trivial as one might think first looking at it and this question was poorly phrased -- it should have been about "filtering out paths from other paths, preserving unaffected trees as a whole".

I ultimately went with the solution below, although it does not preserve empty leafdirs and has the second drawback that it moves each file, when it would be sufficient, to move only a parent tree in some cases.

```
...
comm \
    -23 \
    <(find "${toMove[@]}"  ! -type d 2>/dev/null | sort -u || true) \
    <(find "${exclude[@]}" ! -type d 2>/dev/null | sort -u || true) |
        parallel -j "$(nproc)" -- moveFile {}
...
```

(moveFile is an exported bash function that handles the moving. parallel was used to speed up the (few) times when the script will not operate on one filesystem.)

[Stéphane Chazelas' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/710060/530729) told me a lot I didn't know before and seems to be the way to go, if `zsh` is an option.

Comment: In your desired output, there's `subtree1` for instance in both `tree` and `destination`, so there has to be some copying involved in any case.

Comment: That's correct. Parent directories need to be created in some cases.

Comment: If destination is on a different filesystem, a move implies a copy+delete anyway.

Comment: The script will almost always operate on the same filesystem.

Comment: The standard `pax` utility or `cpio` or GNU `cp` with `-l` can do some copies as hard links (for non-directory files) and a `rename()` is like a `link()+unlink()`. You can exclude stuff with `pax` or `cpio`, or you can remove the things on either side after the linking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of source and destination are on the same filesystem, then a move is a `rename()` which is essentially the same as a `link()`+`unlink()`.

The standard (though not widespread) `pax` command, the (formerly standard) `cpio` command and the GNU implementation of `cp` with `-al` can copy directory structures as symlinks (not for the directories which still need to be created anew), so with `zsh` instead of `bash` and the GNU implementations of `cpio` (for its `-0`/`--null`) and `rm` (for  its `-d`/`--dir` option), you could do:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
src=tree
dst=destination
toMove=(
  subtree1
  subtree2
  subtree3/leaffile3
)
exclude=(
  subtree1/leafdir1
  subtree2/leaffile2
)

set -o extendedglob
autoload zargs

src=$src:P
dst=$dst:P

cd -- $src || exit

allToMove=( $^toMove{,/**/*}~(${(~j[|])exclude})(|/*)(ND) )
print -rNC1 -- $allToMove |
  cpio --pass-through --null --link --make-directories -- $dst &&
  zargs -r -- ${(Oa)allToMove} -- rm -d --
```

We end up creating all target directories anew (and linking all files within) even those we could have just renamed, so that could still be improved but at least none of the data of any non-directory files is being copied.

The directories that are created via `--make-directories` because they're not included in the list to be moved (like the `subtree3` in the example) will not have their metadata (ownership, permission, etc) copied from the source.

You'll see some warnings about directories that can't be removed because they're not empty.

Some of the zsh features used there include:

- `$var:P` expands to the absolute canonical path of the file stored in `$var` as if using standard `realpath()` on it (needed for `$dst` as we `cd` into `$src`, so the relative `destination` path would no longer refer to the same file thereafter).
- `$^array/x` does `rc`/`fish`-like expansion of the array whereby if `$array` contains `A` and `B` as elements for instance, that becomes `Ax` `Bx` instead of `A` `Bx`.
- `A{x,y}` is csh-like brace expansion which similarly expands to `Ax`, `Ay`.
- `**/` matches any level of subdirectories.
- In `glob~pattern`, `~` is the and-not / except `extendedglob` operator used here to apply the exclusions.
- `(${(~j[|])exclude})(|/*)` is the exclusion pattern constructed by `j`oining the elements of the array with `|` (treated as a glob operator and not a literal `|` thanks to the `~` parameter expansion flag), to which we append `(|/*)` to match the elements or any file within.
- `(ND)` glob qualifiers to apply `N`ullglob and `D`otglob to those globs so hidden files are includes and no error is generated if the globs don't match.
- `print -rNC1` prints its arguments `r`aw on `1` `C`olumn, `N`UL-delimited.
- `${(Oa)array}` expands in reverse `a`rray `O`rder, so the leaves are removed before the branches they're on.
- `zargs` is there to avoid the *argument list too long* errors if the list of files to remove is too large.